# Add a second Where in my controller with Laravel

Tags: laravel

how could I add a second option is my state field. That is equal to Charged but also Registered

```
       $detalle = Detalle::where('estado','=','Charged')
        ->where('fecha_hora','=', Carbon :: today())
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You mean it can be Charged OR Registered since column has single value (one of them). Then just simply use orWhere.

```
Detalle::where('estado','=','Charged')->orWhere('estado','=','Registered')
```

Good option would be also whereIn (especially if you have many to compare).

```
Detalle::whereIn('estado', ['Charged', 'Registered'])
```